# is valid Mvp pattern implementation (with rxandroid and retrofit)

Tags: android, design-patterns, rx-java, mvp

I want to get data from remote server using rxandroid in mvp repository. Then,set up grid adapter with data(in Fragment), and replace another fragment for tablet ui(in Activity).

If I use callback listener I need at least 2 callbacks, which to notify async(rxjava) is done to fragment and launch fragment with first record from data set.

Is there alternative way to solve this problem other than callback ??

Actually I am not even sure if I am using rxjava properly.

For now I pass observable back to fragment in order to set adapter and launch new fragment from that returned data.

```
 public <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applySchedulers() {
    return observable -> observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}

@Override
public Observable<MovieDataContainer> getMovieByFilter(String sortBy, String apiKey, int number) {
    MovieApiService movieApiService= retrofit.createService(MovieApiService.class);
    return movieApiService
            .getMovieList(sortBy,apiKey,number)
            .compose(applySchedulers());
}
```

If I am not doing correct way please let me know. If you have sample for this case, it will be grateful

Just in case here is my[git repo](https://github.com/intelcoder/Nanodegree-PopularMovieApp/tree/app_dev/app/src/main/java/com/example/fiddlest/nanodegree_movieapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create these components:

- `ItemsView` and `ItemsPresenter` for displaying items list.
- `DetailsView` and `DetailsPresenter` for displaying item details.
- `NavigationHelper` for managing navigation (eg. open new fragment)

Flow will look like this:

1. `ItemsPresenter.loadData()` loads data using rxJava and retrofit.
2. `ItemsPresenter` calls `ItemsView.showItems(List<Items> list)` (inside you will have something like (`adapter.setContent(list)`)
3. `ItemsPresenter` calls `NavigationHelper.showDetails(Item selectedItem)`. `NavigationHelper` should behave differently depending on phone/tablet.

`ItemsPresenter` could behave differently for phone and for tablet. For phone it calls `NavigationHelper.showDetails` only when user selects item from a list. For table it calls `NavigationHelper.showDetails` also for a first item when data is loaded. I suggest to pass knowledge about phone/table via presenter's constructor.

For example of `ItemsPresenter` -> `ItemsView` flow see [Presenter](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/artemzin/qualitymatters/ui/presenters/ItemsPresenter.java) and [View implementation](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/artemzin/qualitymatters/ui/fragments/ItemsFragment.java)

Comment: Thank you ! But as I asked I dont know what is good way to return data in rxjava callback. I need 2 levels of callback to pass data back to mainactivity to launch fragment(I believe launching new fragment in fragment is bad practice )   And I believe presenter should not have activity(context) then how could you setup adapter(My grid adapter extends arrayAdapter) ?

Comment: Please, take a look at provided examples. You do not need any callbacks. `View` implements interface and `presenter` uses this interface to call `view` directly. `Presenter` shouldn't depend on `context`. Instead it depends on `NavigationHelper` which is also interface with method `showDetails`. For example, your activity can implement `NavigationHelper` interface.

Comment: Isnt interface callback ? In order to invoke function in interface I need to cast to Context .. how can I do that in presenter which does not have access to context

Comment: So you mean I can(or better) pass around Mainview interface to fragment presenter in order to navigate ?

Comment: @user3882878 Sorry, I don't see why you have to cast to Context... Please take a look at provided example of presenter. It works without any dependency on context.

Comment: Maybe I said opposite way. I see this like that      mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;  And I dont really understand your code with my skill..now. Can you tell me where is view() came from ?

Comment: @user3882878 [ItemsPresenter](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/artemzin/qualitymatters/ui/presenters/ItemsPresenter.java) extends [Presenter](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/artemzin/qualitymatters/ui/presenters/Presenter.java) which has `bindView` method. Which is called inside [ItemsFragment](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/artemzin/qualitymatters/ui/fragments/ItemsFragment.java) (see `onViewCreated`)